# if username and password are correct, switch to 2.activity

Tags: java, android, mobile

I'm new to android, I wrote a code for myself, when the button is pressed, it switches to another activity, but I want to connect it to the password and user name.

if "username && password" is correct then switch to activity 2.
how can I do it?

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Giris_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_giris);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.giris);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                openbaslangic();
            }
        });

    }

    public void openbaslangic()
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Baslangic_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
}```
````

Comment: Can you add your layout code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must also find text fields (username and password)

```java
EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username); 
EditText password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

After that you must check validation both field with Your desired values in `openbaslangic()` like this:

```java
if (username.getText().toString() == "your desired username" && password.getText().toString() == "your desired password") {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Baslangic_activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```